# Compute distance between two points on a racetrack

Tags: math, geometry, calculation

I am trying to figure out how to compute the distance between two points on a racetrack. The racetrack is defined by:

`Position center_a; double radius_a; Position center_b; double radius_b;`

Since the two semi-circles that make up the ends of the racetrack can vary in radius, the racetrack is not necessarily uniform. I tried to approach the problem by breaking down the racetrack into straight leg portions and semi-circles, but have a hard time putting it together and generalizing.

Comment: But [what's your actual programming question](/help/how-to-ask)? Because "can someone explain how to do this start to finish" is not what SO is for of course. Explain what you need to do, talk about the solution you thought up, show what code you wrote to do implement that, explain where you got stuck, and what you've already done in terms of debugging and/or (re)searching to get unstuck.